# Story ends with son washing dishes, flinging dishwater outside in the cold

Tags: identification-request

This short story was told by a narrator and was something about an unsavory man. I don't remember how he was unsavory exactly.

The only part I remember is the ending: the narrator is outside the UM's house, and is surprised to see the UM's son come outside with a pot of water -- he'd finished washing the dishes -- and he flings the hot water out into the yard, and it's steaming in the cold (snow?). The narrator was surprised that the son would even do the dishes. IIRC the house was in a rural area.

I believe it was written in English. I read it around 2008. It seemed to be written in fairly modern times, perhaps in the last 50 years or so. It was part of an anthology. I'm thinking it may have been part of a college literature class, but I can't swear to it.

That's about all I remember. Anyone know what this story is?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Is there any more detail you can add to this? For example, when did you read the story, how old was it, was it written in English, translated, was it a novel or short story, any details about names, plotline, book cover? [We also have a checklist which might help to jog your memory.](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info)